# Was this mercenary superhuman?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, supergirl-2015

In the season 3 premiere of *Supergirl*, Kara stops a mercenary (Robert DuBois) from shooting some people. Later, it's revealed that he's involved in a bigger plan, involving alien technology.

However, in stopping him, she knocks him at *least*  fifty feet (probably more) into a car, and he gets up and takes off a few seconds later, barely the worse for wear. Typically, if her opponent is an ordinary human, Supergirl wouldn't do something like that, too.

Is there any evidence that DuBois is superhuman? That is, an alien, a cyborg, wearing high-tech protective armor, etc.?

Comment: [Robert (Bloodsport) DuBois](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloodsport_(comics)#Robert_DuBois) isn't superhuman in any of his [prior incarnations](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Robert_DuBois_(New_Earth)). He has the power to materialise weaponry and is a highly proficient fighter but is only peak-human for strength, resilience and fighting ability

Comment: @Valorum - Can he summon weapons out of thin air? Is that what you mean?

Comment: Lex Luthor gives him a pocket teleporter that allows him to store weapons in hammerspace. Lex also shoved a bunch of high-tech stuff into his weapon-space locker including kryptonite bullets. Not a superpower per se, just tech.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blood Sport is not a superhuman/enhanced individual. The Arrowverse Wiki page on Blood Sport does not have any powers listed, although he does have peak *human* physical condition (https://arrow.fandom.com/wiki/Robert_DuBois). In addition, the only equipment he had was a taser baton.